# Programatically copying data from table from offline database to online database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am working on a desktop application. I have two datasbes. One is on my Local Computer and other is on my server. Both databases contains same table. Now i want that Data from My Local Database must automatically copy into my Server Database.

In Other Words If there is a new Entry in my Local database than that data must be store in my online database also.
Can Anyone Please Tell me How to do that.
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Replication: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx

Comment: Will Replication allow me to do this with Online Database.I tried it using SSMS But it Doesn't Worked for me.

Comment: Are You Sure This will work between local Database and Online Database??

Comment: It will work, as long as your local server isn't an express edition -- express can be subscriber only in all replication scenarios.

Comment: i Tried To Replicate it using SSMS, But It gives me error. it Says Sql server replication Requires Actual Server Name and i am using IP

Comment: Please read the appropriate chapters in SQL Server's books online, or try http://dba.stackexchange.com/. It's really out of scope here.